# How to build with Angular CLI 6 using Typescript 2.8.x

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

In my `angular.json`, I have `cli.warnings.typescriptMismatch` set to false, but when I run `ng build`, I get the error:

```
The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.3 was found instead.
Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.3 was found instead.
```

Is there some other option I need to set?

Comment: Had you tried to install TypeScript 2.7.x(.5 for example) in the app folder?

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want to use features in 2.8.

Comment: Try this `npm install typescript@2.8.0` in the app folder

Comment: `No matching version found for typescript@2.8.0` and it says that it needs to be below `2.8.0` (i.e. `2.7.9` and below).

Comment: If you want to use TS 2.8 you need to use cli version 6.1.0-beta.0.

Comment: @bc1105 The error is not in the cli package. Updating to 6.1.0 appears to produce an unusable `ng new` project producing strange errors about missing packages.